# "AttributeError: 'NoneType' 'write'" & "RuntimeWarning: overflow double_scalars" - received during a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, runtime-error, attributeerror

I'm using a while loop to obtain a backwards decay curve for a radioactive element.

```
import numpy as np
import csv

lmbd=np.log(2)/12.43
year=list(range(-48050,2012))

f=0
decay=[] 
decay.append(0.45)  # concentration of sample during year of sampling

while f<len(year): # Creating the backwards decay curve sample
    p=decay[f]
    x=p/np.exp(-lmbd)
    decay.append(x)
    f=f+1

print(decay)
```

When I run the above code I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 13, in
>
> ```
> x=p/np.exp(-lmbd)
> ```
>
> File "C:\Python32\lib\idlelib\PyShell.py", line 59, in idle_showwarning
>       file.write(warnings.formatwarning(message, category, filename,
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

However, if I substitute `len(year)` with, for example, `50` then the loop runs smoothly. If I substitute `len(year)` with `50062` (the value of `len(year)`) I still get the error.

1. Could the error occurring due to the length of the iterations? (though this surely mustn't be the case)
2. Why is it working for 50 but not 50062?
3. Can it be that the numbers just get too big as I'm creating exponential growth over 50000 years? (I wanted to keep that many years as I use the same script for other elements which have a smaller `lmbd` value so values don't get so large)
4. Any possibilities for fixing?

I'm using Python 3.2

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code, and it runs fine for me.

Comment: I got `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars`. In order to avoid the overflow, I stopped at `inf`, by changing the loop condition: `while f<len(year) and decay[-1] != np.inf:`

Comment: I get `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars x=p/np.exp(-lmbd)`

Comment: This is not an error in your problem but an error in the environment "Python Shell" that wants to show the error. You may be able to see the original error if you execute this without the Python Shell.

Comment: If you're running IDLE with "-n" (no subprocess) and no console/terminal for `stderr`, you could try the following to see warnings: `import sys, idlelib.PyShell; idlelib.PyShell.warning_stream = sys.stderr`. In this case `sys.stderr` is a `PyShell.PseudoOutputFile`.

Comment: @PaF Thanks for the help.  I still get the warning when add the extra bits to the while statement, but seems to work fine

Comment: @User Thanks for the help. Yes, I was able to see the original error when I ran it in CMD

Comment: @eryksun Thanks for the help. Yes, I was using IDLE and your addition made the correct error come up

Comment: I've combined all your suggestions in an answer to close off the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to *PaF*, *User*, and *eryksun* for providing the answers (in the comments) :

1. I was getting the wrong warning (in IDLE) in regards to the script.

   - If I ran the script in `cmd` (as per *User* suggestions) I got the `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars x=p/np.exp(-lmbd)` error.
   - Also if I added  `import sys, idlelib.PyShell; idlelib.PyShell.warning_stream = sys.stderr` to the script (as per *eruksun* suggestion) I also get the correct error in IDLE (which I was using).
   - The script can now run to completion but the decay list has a whole lot of `inf` values at the end which is dealt with in the next point.
2. To deal with the `overflow` problem:

   - I tried replacing the `while` statement with `while f<len(year) and decay[-1] != np.inf:` (as per *PaF* suggestion). The loop stops once the last value in the `decay` list reaches `inf`; however, it attaches a single `inf` value to the end of the list. Additionally, the `overflow` error remains.
   - I instead added an `if` statement within the loop to exit once `inf` is reached but before appending to the list (however, the `overflow` error still comes up but produces a list without any `inf` values in it)

The updated script, which works, is:

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import sys, idlelib.PyShell; idlelib.PyShell.warning_stream = sys.stderr

lmbd=np.log(2)/12.43
year=list(range(-48050,2012))

f=0
decay=[] 
decay.append(0.45)# concentration of sample during year of sampling

while f<len(year):  # Creating the backwards decay equation for each sample
    p=decay[f]
    x=p/np.exp(-lmbd)
    if x==np.inf:
        break
    decay.append(x)
    f=f+1

print(decay)
print("end")
```

While this still gives the `overflow` error in both IDLE and CMD, I think that is OK for my purposes as I'm not worried about the extremely large numbers and the script runs to completion.